# Select Mysql table_name from information_schema.tables not working

Tags: mysql, select, union, information-schema

I am trying to select table_name from information_schema.tables but it is not working.
I am doing union select and my statement looks like:

```
Select * from users where name='a' union select 1,2,table_name,4,5,6,7 from information_schema.tables; --
```

If I use 3 instead of table_name then SQL statement is working, I can also select version and other things which are present in the information_schema.tables. But if I want select table_name then it is not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me. What error/result are you getting?

Comment: Something like error database query, it is an application logic error, i don't have access to the mysql logs and administration.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? What's the error message?